# need to reverse animate the keyframe when mouse is done of hovering

Tags: html, css, web, css-animations

so I am a html and css starter, I wanted to make this cool startup animation which when hovered will rotate and expand like in the code and later I am planing to add a button in between. Till now it works fine but I am stuck on how can I reverse animate it to close, when the mouse in not hovering and also the code is very lengthy so is there a way to make it shorter.

↑ I know this isn't the best explanation. so if you dont understand just run the code and maybe you'll get it.

```css
/* 
=======================
Variable
=======================
*/

:root {

  /* -----colors----- */

  --clr-blue-1: #0C164F;
  --clr-blue-2: #5643FD;

  --clr-purple-1: #0D0717;
  --clr-purple-2: #1D1135;
  --clr-purple-3: #7649FE;

  --clr-gray-1: #B9A2FE;
  --clr-white: #FCFBFE;

  --clr-pink-1: #BA1E68;

  /* -----fonts----- */

  --ff-primary: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
  --ff-secondary: 'Nova Square', cursive;

  /* --cross animation-- */

  --cross-animation-time: 1s;

  --cross-opacity: 0.6;

  /* -----other----- */

  --transition: all 0.3s linear;

  --spacing: 0.25rem;

}

/* 
=======================
Global CSS
=======================
*/

* {

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

  box-sizing: border-box;

}

body {

  font-family: var(--ff-primary);

  background-color: var(--clr-white);

  color: var(--clr-purple-1);

  line-height: 1.5;

  font-size: 0.875rem; /* 14 px */

}

a {

  text-decoration: none;

}

img {

  display: block;

  width: 100%;

}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {

  text-transform: capitalize;
  letter-spacing: var(--spacing);
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 1.25;

}

h1 { font-size: 3rem; }

h2 { font-size: 2rem; }

h3 { font-size: 1.5rem; }

h4 { font-size: 0.875rem; }

p { margin-bottom: 1.25rem; }

.clearfix::after, .clearfix::before{

  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;

}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {

  h1 { font-size: 4rem; }

  h2 { font-size: 2.5rem; }

  h3 { font-size: 2rem; }

  h4 { font-size: 1rem; }
  
}

/* 
=======================
Header Section
=======================
*/

.header {

  min-height: 100vh;

  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/17520.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

  text-align: center;

  display: flex;

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}

.head-arrows {

  background: var(--clr-white);

  opacity: 0.4;

  display: inline-block;

}

.inline-breaker {

  display: block;

}

.arrow-left, .arrow-right {

  display: inline-block;

}

.arrow-left {

  margin-right: 1.5rem;

}

.arrow-right {

  margin-left: 1.5rem;

}

.arrow-up-left {

  width: 1.5rem;

  height: 6rem;

  transform: skewY(45deg);

  /* animation: CrossUpLeft 1s ease-in-out 1; */

}

.banner:hover .arrow-up-left {

  animation: CrossUpLeft var(--cross-animation-time) ease-in-out 1;

  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

.arrow-up-right {

  width: 1.5rem;

  height: 6rem;

  transform: skewY(-45deg);

  /* animation: CrossUpRight 1s ease-in-out 1; */

}

.banner:hover .arrow-up-right {

  animation: CrossUpRight var(--cross-animation-time) ease-in-out 1;

  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

.arrow-left-up {

  display: block;

  width: 6rem;

  height: 1.5rem;

  transform: skewX(45deg);

}

.banner:hover .arrow-left-up {

  animation: CrossLeftUp var(--cross-animation-time) ease-in-out 1;

  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

.arrow-left-down {

  display: block;

  width: 6rem;

  height: 1.5rem;

  transform: skewX(-45deg);

}

.banner:hover .arrow-left-down {

  animation: CrossLeftDown var(--cross-animation-time) ease-in-out 1;

  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

.arrow-right-up {

  display: block;

  width: 6rem;

  height: 1.5rem;

  transform: skewX(-45deg);

}

.banner:hover .arrow-right-up {

  animation: CrossRightUp var(--cross-animation-time) ease-in-out 1;

  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

.arrow-right-down {

  display: block;

  width: 6rem;

  height: 1.5rem;

  transform: skewX(45deg);

}

.banner:hover .arrow-right-down {

  animation: CrossRightDown var(--cross-animation-time) ease-in-out 1;

  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

.arrow-down-left {

  width: 1.5rem;

  height: 6rem;

  transform: skewY(-45deg);

}

.banner:hover .arrow-down-left {

  animation: CrossDownLeft var(--cross-animation-time) ease-in-out 1;

  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}


.arrow-down-right {

  width: 1.5rem;

  height: 6rem;

  transform: skewY(45deg);

}

.banner:hover .arrow-down-right {

  animation: CrossDownRight var(--cross-animation-time) ease-in-out 1;

  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

/* 
=======================
Animation Section
=======================
*/

@keyframes CrossUpLeft {

  5% {

    transform: translate(0rem,-1rem) skewY(45deg);

  }

  50% {

    transform: translate(-6rem,4.5rem) skewY(45deg);

  }

  95% {

    transform: translate(0rem,15rem) skewY(45deg);

  }

  100% {

    opacity: var(--cross-opacity);

    transform: translate(0,13rem) skewY(45deg);

  }

}

@keyframes CrossUpRight {

  5% {

    transform: translate(0rem,-1rem) skewY(-45deg);

  }

  50% {

    transform: translate(-6rem,4.5rem) skewY(-45deg);

  }

  95% {

    transform: translate(0rem,15rem) skewY(-45deg);

  }

  100% {

    opacity: var(--cross-opacity);

    transform: translate(0,13rem) skewY(-45deg);

  }

}

@keyframes CrossLeftUp {

  5% {

    transform: translate(-1rem,0) skewX(45deg);

  }

  50% {

    transform: translate(4.5rem,6rem) skewX(45deg);

  }

  95% {

    transform: translate(15rem,0) skewX(45deg);

  }

  100% {

    opacity: var(--cross-opacity);

    transform: translate(13rem,0) skewX(45deg);

  }

}

@keyframes CrossLeftDown {

  5% {

    transform: translate(-1rem,0) skewX(-45deg);

  }

  50% {

    transform: translate(4.5rem,6rem) skewX(-45deg);

  }

  95% {

    transform: translate(15rem,0) skewX(-45deg);

  }

  100% {

    opacity: var(--cross-opacity);

    transform: translate(13rem,0) skewX(-45deg);

  }

}

@keyframes CrossRightUp {

  5% {

    transform: translate(1rem,0) skewX(-45deg);

  }

  50% {

    transform: translate(-4.5rem,-6rem) skewX(-45deg);

  }

  95% {

    transform: translate(-15rem,0) skewX(-45deg);

  }

  100% {

    opacity: var(--cross-opacity);

    transform: translate(-13rem,0) skewX(-45deg);

  }

}

@keyframes CrossRightDown {

  5% {

    transform: translate(1rem,0) skewX(45deg);

  }

  50% {

    transform: translate(-4.5rem,-6rem) skewX(45deg);

  }

  95% {

    transform: translate(-15rem,0) skewX(45deg);

  }

  100% {

    opacity: var(--cross-opacity);

    transform: translate(-13rem,0) skewX(45deg);

  }

}

@keyframes CrossDownLeft {

  5% {

    transform: translate(0,1rem) skewY(-45deg);

  }

  50% {

    transform: translate(6rem,-4.5rem) skewY(-45deg);

  }

  95% {

    transform: translate(0,-15rem) skewY(-45deg);

  }

  100% {

    opacity: var(--cross-opacity);

    transform: translate(0,-13rem) skewY(-45deg);

  }

}

@keyframes CrossDownRight {

  5% {

    transform: translate(0,1rem) skewY(45deg);

  }

  50% {

    transform: translate(6rem,-4.5rem) skewY(45deg);

  }

  95% {

    transform: translate(0,-15rem) skewY(45deg);

  }

  100% {

    opacity: var(--cross-opacity);

    transform: translate(0,-13rem) skewY(45deg);

  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- ----------------------------CSS link--------------------------- -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <!-- --------------------------Google fonts------------------------- -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@300;400;500&family=Nova+Square&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- --------------------------Font Awesome------------------------- -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\com\Desktop\AFFAN\VisualStudio Codes\ICONS\fontawesome-free-5.15.4-web\css\all.css">

  <title>Index</title>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- ---------------------------
           Header section
  ---------------------------- -->

  <header class="header">

    <div class="banner">

      <div class="head-arrows arrow-up-left"></div><div

      class="head-arrows arrow-up-right"></div><div class="inline-breaker"></div><div class="arrow-left">
        
        <div class="head-arrows arrow-left-up"></div>
        <div class="head-arrows arrow-left-down"></div>

    </div><div class="arrow-right">
        
    <div class="head-arrows arrow-right-up"></div>
    <div class="head-arrows arrow-right-down"></div></div><div 
    
    class="inline-breaker"></div><div 
    
    class="head-arrows arrow-down-left"></div><div

    class="head-arrows arrow-down-right"></div>

  </div>

  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you add fiddle for this ?

Comment: Thanks for adding a working snippet - makes it much easier to see what's going on. Just to clarify, do you want the system to run exactly the same animation only in reverse when the hover is over?

Comment: yea exactly that in ease-in-out format but in reverse

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516793/how-to-reverse-an-animation-on-mouse-out-after-hover

Comment: Or maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710237/reversing-a-keyframe-animation-on-hover-out

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).